# enable_shared_from_this derived class methods are undefined reference

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm using apache's [parquet-cpp](https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp/blob/master/src/parquet/statistics.h) library (click the link to see the file in question). Line 82 is defined the class RowGroupStatistics that inherits from std::enable_shared_from_this, and line 132 the class TypedRowGroupStatistics that inherits from RowGroupStatistics.

In my code I only have:

```
shared_ptr<RowGroupStatistics> stats = ...;
shared_ptr<Int32Statistics> stats2 = static_pointer_cast<Int32Statistics>(ccm.statistics());
```

Where Int32Statistics is defined at the end of the statistics as a templated class of TypedRowGroupStatistics.

When I try to use the min or max method of the TypedRowGroupStatistics pointer as such

```
stats2->min();
```

I get a compilation error:

```
undefined reference to `parquet::TypedRowGroupStatistics<parquet::DataType<(parquet::Type::type)1> >::min() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My guess is I'm using the enable_shared_from_this feature wrong, but I can't figure out what is the correct way to cast the base pointer to a derived class and use its methods.

Comment: It's a linker error, there's nothing wrong with your code. My guess is you didn't include parquet-cpp's libs in the linker search path.

Comment: I mean I use pretty much all of parquet-cpp functionnality in my code. I manage to use the library to read files, and read metadata to print header infos. But the only thing I can't manage to print in the header are these statistics since there is this compilation problem.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I think I did but I don't work at that company anymore, and I don't remember what I did. Sorry